# Custom Keyboard send input to textfield

Tags: iphone, keyboard, custom-controls

I have my custom keyboard setup. I have buttons created. But how do I pass on the value pressed as if it was a normal keyboard?

For instance if the tap my button labeled "1" I want to send that to the uitextfield that has my custom input as it's inputView, or whatever textfield is the firstresponder with my custom keyboard.

I'm sure this is simple...

Comment: I know I could assign the UITextField to my custom keyboard but what I'm really curious is how the iPhone's keyboard just passes it's input. Surely there must be a simple delegate method or something?

Comment: Is UITextInput protocol what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITextField textfield; //your textfield

- (void) whenButtonIsClicked{
    textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textfield.text, NEW_CHARACTER_FROM_BUTTON_CLICK];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom keyboard has a delegate or should have a delegate for button presses on your custom keyboard view, hasn't it?
If so, the exemplary delegate implementation for a button press could look like this, for a custom number pad for example:

```
- (void) customKeyboardView: (YourCustomKeyboardView*) customKeyboardView didTapButtonAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index {
    if (index == 9) {
        // Tapped empty button
    } else if (index == 11) {
        // Back Button Tapped
        NSString* input = self.yourTextField.text;
        if ([input length] > 0 )
            self.yourTextField.text = [input substringToIndex: [input length] - 1];
    } else {
        self.yourTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.yourTextField.text, [self titleForButtonAtIndex: index]];
    }
}
```